# TypeScript Project Templates Missing

Tags: typescript

I have Visual Studio installed in a non-default location (my d:), and the TypeScript templates seem to install in c: regardless.  How can I get the Project Template to register with VS?  I tried copying the templates over, but I'm not sure how to register them.

Answer (score 1):

Try re-installing the TypeScript plugin from http://www.typescriptlang.org/.

Make sure VisualStudio is shut down during the process.

Comment: Also, make sure that you delete the ProjectTemplateCache and ItemTemplateCache folders inside the VS install dir.